# Handling resource xml files

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I'm new to development and would like to clarify a couple of simple points, 
When I create a new drawable xml file I place it in the "drawable-hdpi" folder and only that folder, I can access it fine like so....

```
 android:src="@drawable/button_border"
```

but is that the correct correct way? or should they be in their own folder in the res folder, or just the file placed in the res folder and not in any particular sub-folder?
also if I wanted to create a `arrays.xml` file what folder should that be created in.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray and for drawables http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays should go to the values folder, so res/values/arrays.xml, as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

As for the images, it is a good practice to provide relevant images in each drawable folder according to the screen sizes you plan to support for your app, or some of your users will end up seeing badly sized images, more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). You can use the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) to generate icons, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do create the relevant images for each screen size unfortunately photo doesn't show that, and coincidentally I use Android asset studio as it takes a lot of the work out of it. In regards to the 'shape drawables ? what folder should they be placed in.

Comment: Since shape drawables should be independent of the screen size because they are defined in xml, they should be placed in drawable-nodpi. You can create that folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I just took a look at the documentation in the link provided by Raghunandan and it seems to state that they should be placed in res/drawable/filename.xml as I have no folder named just drawable so should this be created by myself? Or is creating a folder named drawable-nodpi the same thing? I'll lean towards your knowledge. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, they could be placed inside res/drawable/ or res/drawable-nodpi/, both will work, I don't remember where I saw nodpi being used but I liked the fact that it says it all in the name, like for the other drawable folders, so I kept that as best practice. It's up to you, use what you prefer ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it does seem nicer to have it denote what it purpose is, like in the name for the rest of the folders, I'll follow your best practice. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The different xml file like attr.xml, colors.xml, arrays.xml, dimens.xml, font.xml, strings.xml, styles.xml should be kept in the res/values folder.

The others custom xml file should be keep in the drawable folder.